# Add EventListener in every change of an innerHTML in an div

Tags: javascript, html, dom, containers, addeventlistener

Just for curiosity I want to get an event every time i add html code to a div like this

```
const xData = 40;

const container = document.querySelector('.container');

container.innerHTML = `<div class="container_Addons">${xData}</div>`;

container.addEventListener('i dont know',function(){
     console.log("you have just added some exotic stuff!");
});

for (i= 0; i<10;i++){
     container.innerHTML += `<div class="container_Addons">${i}st ${xData}</div>`;
};
```

to get an listener working every time i add html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver) is quite easy to watch an element's `childList` change:

```js
// Utility functions:
const el = (sel, par) => (par ||document).querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);
const repeat = (n, cb) => [...Array(n)].forEach((_, i) => cb(i));


// Task: watch content changes:

const xData = 40;
const container = el('.container');

const observeInsertion = new MutationObserver((records, observer) => {
  records.forEach(rec => {
    rec.addedNodes.forEach(node => {
      console.log(`Added some exotic stuff: ${node.textContent}`);
    })
  });
});

observeInsertion.observe(container, {
  childList: true
});

repeat(10, i => {
  const elAddon = elNew("div", {
    className: "container_Addons",
    textContent: `${i}st ${xData}`,
  });
  container.append(elAddon);
});
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

The `innerHTML` constantly changes an element's full contents, therefore I opted for the much more suitable [Element.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) method - in order to only be notified for that one specific child insertion. You can as well use `.innerHTML =`  instead of `.append()`, but in such case you'll have to do extra useless and complicated work to detect what is exactly that was *newly* inserted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe) with `childList: true` to subscribe to specific DOM changes:

```js
const content = document.querySelector('#content');

const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
  console.log(`innerHTML updated, ${ mutationsList.length } mutation${ mutationsList.length > 1 ? 's' : '' }`);
});

observer.observe(content, { childList: true });

for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
   content.innerHTML += `<p>New element ${ i }</p>`;
};

setTimeout(() => {
  content.innerHTML += `<p>Added from setTimeout()</p>`;
})

setTimeout(() => {
  content.innerHTML += `<p>Added after 5 seconds</p>`;
}, 5000)
```

```css
#content {
  padding-bottom: 67px;
}

#content > p {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  background: cyan;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 32px;
}

#content > p + p {
  margin: 8px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p>0</p>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
  <p>5</p>
  <p>6</p>
  <p>7</p>
  <p>8</p>
  <p>9</p>
</div>
```

Note, however, that your `MutationObserver`'s callback won't be invoked for every single statement that's executed that updates `.innerHTML` (as they might cause a single paint, like the ones inside the `for` in the example above), but you can get the list of updated elements from `mutationsList`.

However, if new elements are added at different points in time (like the one inside `setTimeout`), your callback will be invoked for each update.